# Overriding System.out.println

Tags: java

How can I override `System.out.println()`?

Like I would override `toString()`;

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "x";
}
```

I want to make it so, that when you call

```
System.out.println(OBJECT);
```

It would print the attributes of the object instead of the reference.

Comment: If you override `toString` in the object's class, then it will print whatever you want.

Comment: *Which* attribute of the object? Different objects will have different "attributes". Do you mean you want to print each object's toString() method?

Comment: Also, Overriding the  `toString` method and the `System.out.println()` would not give the same result. Those are two different method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strictly, the answer to your question "How can I override System.out.println()?" is that you can replace `System.out` with an alternative `PrintStream` using [`System.setOut`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-). The `PrintStream` you supply can implement `println` however you like (*).

But this is *almost certainly* not what you mean. You can override the `toString()` method on your class instead, and then this will be used in all places that want to build a string representation of your instance, not simply `System.out.println`.

---

(*) However if you want to conform to the specification, you don't have that much flexibility, e.g. `println(Object)` "calls `String.valueOf(x)`".

Answer (score 3):

Overriding `System.out.println` IS NOT what you need. In order to do that you would need to extend PrintStream and override all overloaded version of the method printLn. After that you would need to replace the standart stream of your JVM by calling `System.setOut()`.

Every java object has the capability of converting it self to a string representation. In order to "customize" this representation you need to override the `toString()` method.

printLn will always call `toString()` independently of the class of your object. That's waht we call polimorphism.

So override to `toString()` for each class you want a special string representation.